Unique $n$th roots in algebraically closed fields with characteristic $p>0$
Is the following statement correct (true):
If $p>0$ is prime, $n$ is a positive integer that is co-prime to $p$ (that is, $p$ does not divide $n$), and $\mathbb{F}$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, then for every $a\in\mathbb{F}$, there is a unique element $b\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $b^n=a$.
Existence follows immediately from the fact that$\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed. I cannot complete a proof of the uniqueness, nor do I have a counter-example.

As @ArturoMagidin points out, the roots of your polynomial are all distinct. But you should think about what happens in the case where $n$ is a power of $p$.

$x^2=1$ has two solutions in $\Bbb F_3$, which is contained in its algebraic closure.

This is false: every $a\neq0$ has $n$ distinct roots. To see this, note that $f(x)= x^n-a$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$, and since $f'(x)= nx^{n-1}\neq 0$ (because $\gcd(n,p)=1$), then $f$ and $f'$ have no common roots, so $f$ has $n$ pairwise distinct roots.
Now, if drop the hypothesis that $\gcd(n,p)=1$, then write $n=p^rm$ with $\gcd(m,p)=1$. If $u$ is a $p^r$th root of $a$, then $(x-u)^{p^r}= x^{p^r}-a$, so $u$ is the unique $p^r$th root of $a$. Now $u$ has $m$ distinct $m$th roots by the previous paragraph, and they are all $n$th roots of $a$. Conversely, if $q$ is an $n$th root of $a$, then $q^m$ is a $p^r$th root of $a$, so $q^m=u$, hence $q$ is an $m$th root of $u$. Thus, $a\neq 0$ has exactly $m$ $n$th roots in $\mathbb{F}$.
In particular, $a\neq0$ has a unique $n$th root if and only if $n$ is a power of $p$.
